# Python error - curses is not supported on this machine

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, tensorflow, compiler-warnings, tflearn

I want to program a small chatbot. I am following a [youtube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wypVcNIH6D4&t=587s) and I tried to import different modules, which can be seen in the code:

```
import nltk
from nltk.stem.lancaster import LancasterStemmer
stemmer = LancasterStemmer()

import numpy
import tflearn
import tensorflow
import random
import json
```

When I try to run the code, the following error appears:

```
C:\Users\timsi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\dtypes.py:493: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_qint8 = np.dtype([("qint8", np.int8, 1)])
C:\Users\timsi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\dtypes.py:494: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_quint8 = np.dtype([("quint8", np.uint8, 1)])
C:\Users\timsi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\dtypes.py:495: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_qint16 = np.dtype([("qint16", np.int16, 1)])
C:\Users\timsi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\dtypes.py:496: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_quint16 = np.dtype([("quint16", np.uint16, 1)])
C:\Users\timsi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\dtypes.py:497: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_qint32 = np.dtype([("qint32", np.int32, 1)])
C:\Users\timsi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\dtypes.py:502: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  np_resource = np.dtype([("resource", np.ubyte, 1)])
curses is not supported on this machine (please install/reinstall curses for an optimal experience)
```

Comment: Did you follow the error outputs suggestion of installing/reinstalling the `curses` package? What was the result?

Comment: ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement curses (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for curses

Comment: I would look at the documentation for curses, it may have alternatives for installation.

Answer (score 2):

Following the same tutorial got me here. I found this to help on Windows OS. I suppose Windows was not considered by the author of said tutorial...

```
pip install windows-curses
```